# Confused by how !empty() works in my if-condition

Tags: php, isset, is-empty

I'm confused by what counts as empty in this code logic. I have a variable amount of table rows (additional rows are dynamically inserted via ajax) that each accept four inputs. The logic I want is for a particular row - whose inputs are incomplete - to be unable to update a database:

```
if ((isset($_POST['_branch']) && !empty($_POST['_branch'])) 
&& (isset($_POST['_day']) && !empty($_POST['_day']))
&& (isset($_POST['_starttimepicker']) && !empty($_POST['_starttimepicker']))
&& (isset($_POST['_endtimepicker']) && !empty($_POST['_endtimepicker']))) {
    $b_id = $_POST['_branch'];
    $w_date = $_POST['_day'];
    $s_time = $_POST['_starttimepicker'];
    $e_time = $_POST['_endtimepicker'];

// ... rest of code comes here
}
```

The code snippet where the four inputs are handled:

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_starttimepicker" name="_starttimepicker[]"  placeholder="Enter Time" />
</td>
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_endtimepicker" name="_endtimepicker[]"  placeholder="Enter Time" />
</td>
```

When I have start time and end time "empty" (haven't interacted with them; the placeholder remains as "Enter Time"), the if-condition logic above still processes and the database is ultimately updated (with bad values). Even when I try to play around with the default value parameter (I have value = "" and "red"):

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_starttimepicker" name="_starttimepicker[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Time" />
</td>
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_endtimepicker" name="_endtimepicker[]" value="red" placeholder="Enter Time" />
</td>
```

The if logic still processes (also, the relevant database value where I had value="red" remains as "". I thought it would have taken the default value "red", so maybe I'm misunderstanding this).

What am I misunderstanding? Any advice?

Comment: 1. You don't have to use `isset()` with `empty()` while you check `$_POST` with `empty()` before use it, with just `empty()` is enough - no need `isset()`. It is not related to question but can be improve.

Comment: 2. Your `if` conditions are **all** fields **must** be filled and not empty. That means `_branch`, `_day`, `_starttimepicker`, `_endtimepicker` must be filled. The input with empty value (`<input value="">`) will be **always** ignored and not pass these conditions. So, it is not possible that your update/insert DB will work inside this condition without form filled.

Comment: 3. The problem is with your insert/update DB part but you did not showing that code. The problem is somewhere around that part but not showing here. And I don't think it work inside `if` because if all of your form field did not fill then it is not possible to work.

Comment: @vee thanks. In my testing, some fields are being left empty - at least to my understanding - so I don't understand why the code inside the if condition is running. The inside code is definitely running, so I have to review why the fields are being treated as not empty.

Comment: You can test your empty form fields with `var_dump(empty($_POST['your_form_field']));` for all of them to see which field is not empty but I confirm that it is not possible to work if not all of them are filled. Test with this to see which field is `false`.

Comment: I agree with you, but apparently that's not the case. I'm running var_dump() inside the if condition and it's returning empty values such as "0 => string '' (length=0)" and correct values for inputs I fill.

Comment: I see the problem now, it is in my answer below.

Comment: You are checking that the arrays are not empty, and each dynamically inserted row adds to the arrays, so if one row is filled in they will not be empty no matter how many empty rows there are. You need to loop through and check for a value in each with the same index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you use input arrays. To check empty form fields that are input arrays, you need more complicate than just `empty()`.

Example HTML form:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_starttimepicker" name="_starttimepicker[]"  placeholder="Enter Time" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="_endtimepicker" name="_endtimepicker[]"  placeholder="Enter Time" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is PHP function to check it and how to use.

```php
$_starttimepicker = ($_POST['_starttimepicker'] ?? []);
// in PHP older than 7.0 use (isset($_POST['_starttimepicker']) ? $_POST['_starttimepicker'] : []) instead.
$_endtimepicker = ($_POST['_endtimepicker'] ?? []);

/**
 * Check if ANY fields are empty.
 *
 * @param array $fields The input form field, one by one.
 * @return bool Return `true` if one of a form field is empty. Return `false` for otherwise.
 */
function isEmptyFields(...$fields) 
{
    $foundEmpty = false;
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (is_array($field) && !empty($field)) {
            foreach ($field as $index => $value) {
                if (empty($value)) {
                    $foundEmpty = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (empty($field)) {
                $foundEmpty = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $foundEmpty;
}
if (!isEmptyFields($_starttimepicker, $_endtimepicker)) {
    // if all fields are NOT empty.
    echo 'save your data.';
}
```

Tested submit the form by filled all fields, the result is in condition (*save your data.*) but if empty just one, it will not goes into `if` condition.